# NodeJs - Return dynamic filename on response doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-platform

When i response with the static filename everything works fine

```javascript
return res.download(filePath, 'test.pptx');
```

however when i response with the dynamic filename, the file comes named as **download**.

```javascript
return res.download(filePath, fileName);
```

The files is coming from folder called **ready_files**.

The complete function below:

```javascript
async function downloadPPT(req, res) {
    const readyFilesPath = path.resolve(pptProcessFolderPath, 'ready_files');
    const files = fs.readdirSync(readyFilesPath);

    if(files.length > 1){
        const zipFile = files.map(e => {
            return {
                path: path.resolve(readyFilesPath, e),
                name: e
            }
        });

        return res.zip(zipFile, 'PPTs.zip');
    }

    const filePath = path.resolve(readyFilesPath, files[0])
    const fileName = files[0]

    return res.download(filePath, fileName);
}
```

Some details:

- When dynamic filename sent, the **Content-Disposition** header is not coming.
- I'am running the code in Docker Container hosted by Google Cloud Run.
- When i run docker locally works fine, error occur just on GCP.
- When i set static filename on GCP, it's works fine.
- ExpressJS version: **^4.17.1**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /home

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: And what is the value of `filePath` and `fileName` in that case? Please add a `console.log(filePath + '  ' +fileName)` right before your `return res.download(filePath, fileName);` and show what you get as a output log.

Comment: The output of console.log: `/home/PPTs/ready_files/10.2022 - Amadeus - Sulamerica - Análise de Gestão e Risco.pptx 10.2022 - Amadeus - Sulamerica - Análise de Gestão e Risco.pptx`. That is the path of PPTX inside docker and the file name, both are strings.